# Unable to read a number from a text file

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I am using Fortran to make a subroutine to use in a CFD shallow water software.

I have written this code to read and use the values stored.

```
PROGRAM hieto

! Calcula la precipitacion efectiva en funcion del tiempo
!IMPLICIT NONE

real::a

!Abrir CSV
!OPEN(UNIT=10,FILE="datos.txt",FORM="formatted",STATUS="replace",ACTION="readwrite",ACCESS='sequential')
open(unit=10, file='datos.txt')

!Leer el archivo
read(10, *, iostat=ios)a
print*,ios
print*, a
close (UNIT=10)

END PROGRAM hieto
```

My text file `datos`, looks like this

```
1

2

3
```

When I run the code as is, I get the following output

```
-1 
0.0000000000
Process return 0 (0x0) execution time: 0.002 s
```

the first number in the row one is one not zero, so I don't know why this happens.

And if I remove the `iostat=ios` from the read statement, I get the following error:

```
At ine 13 (the line od the read stament) of file /home/Dropbox/scripts_tesis/fortran/hieto_telemac.f90 (unit=10, file=datos.txt')
Fortran runtime error: end of file.
Proceess returned 2 (0x2)
```

I have read some answers here so I tried adding `end=3` in the  read statement, and also to end my text file with a blank line at the end.
The `end=3` gives an error saying 3 is not a defined label and putting a blank row in the text file  does nothing.

I am using ubuntu 16.04 LTS and Gfortran compiler.

Comment: thank you for answering but i did read up on this , and use How do I read until the end of a file (EOF)? portion of this Wiki  Fortran (http://fortranwiki.org/fortran/show/FAQ).  i changed the code to make it run, but i had previously  attempt this.

Answer (score 4):

What happens is that your file is empty.

Make sure that there is indeed a file called `datos.txt` in that directory. Pay attention to the exact name. `datos.txt` and just `datos` is not the same thing.

If you tried to open it before with the commented command that includes `STATUS="replace"` your old file would have been *replaced*.

And because the file is empty, you didn't real anything useful. If `iostat` is non-zero, and your is `-1`, then the value of the variable being read is undefined. So your `a` is undefined. Again, because your file is empty.

Additionally, you cannot just blindly put `end=3` in your code because you saw it somewhere on Stack Overflow. You must first understand what it is supposed to do. There is no reason to combine `iostat=` and `end=`. The `iostat` is perfectly sufficient.

Comment: And have a look how I edited your post. Use capital (big) I for the word "I". Do not put space before a comma (`,`). Start sentences with a capital (big) letter. I am quite sure your native language has similar rules.

Comment: To avoid these problems use `status='old'`, definitely not `status='replace`'.

Comment: Theseare basic text writing rules. No special posting rules. I am sure you own language has very similar rules.

Comment: I like using INQUIRE(... EXIST=Prego), and then chucking an error if the logical Prego is .FALSE., however STATUS='old' does similar.